# Hash saved in Chinese instead of standard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a procedure in SQL Server to enter a new user.

When I'm going to create the hash password that appears in the Chinese language, I couldn't understand why.

Can someone help me with the solution and also explain to me why this happened?

Script:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Administrative].[spInsertUser]
    (@Name         Nvarchar(50),
     @Surname      Nvarchar(Max),
     @Email        Nvarchar(1000),
     @PasswordHash Nvarchar(Max),
     @EmailConfirmed Bit,
     @Lockout   Bit,
     @TimeZone  Nvarchar(6))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id Bigint;
    DECLARE @NewPasswordHash Varbinary(Max);

    SET @NewPasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @PasswordHash);

    INSERT INTO Administrative.Users ([Name], Surname, Email,   PasswordHash, 
                                      EmailConfirmed, Lockout, TimeZone, Active)
    VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @Email, @NewPasswordHash,
            1, 0, @TimeZone, 1)

    SET @Id = @@Identity

    SELECT @Id AS Id
END
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Created with varbinary:

[image]

> Error

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Administrative.spInsertUser Procedure, Line 0 [Batch 8 Start Line]
> Implicit cast from varchar data type to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: It's not "saved in Chinese" you're taking a hashed value, which is a binary value, and converting it back to a string based data type and expecting something sensible... It's a hashed value, of course it's going to be non-sensical.

Comment: `@NewPasswordHash` is a VARBINARY, but you're storing it in an NVARCHAR when it should be stored in a VARBINARY.

Comment: Even though the column data type is varbinary, it saves that way.

Comment: Please check your table schema again. If `PasswordHash` were a `varbinary` column then SSMS would display its values with `0x` followed by hexadecimal characters.

Comment: @ThiagoCorrêa In `ALTER Procedure [Administrative].[spInsertUser](` it says `,   @PasswordHash   Nvarchar(Max)`.

Comment: Aside... prefer to use `scope_identity()` instead of `@@identity`. The `@@identity` value is unreliable in the presence of triggers and has several other annoyances.

Comment: I edited the end of the form, could you please check to help me?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Why is it unreliable?

Comment: If you have an insert trigger that records information into an audit table, for example, the `@@identity` value in your code is most likely going to get the record ID from the audit table instead of your own.

Comment: Change the column type `ALTER TABLE Administrative.Users ALTER PasswordHash binary(64) NOT NULL;`

Comment: Other commenters have pointed you in the right direction (the data type of the column), but an observation: why are you passing a variable called `@Password Hash` through a hashing function? It's either a hash (in which case there nothing to do) or is an actual password (in which case the variable should be renamed, but also there will be plaintext passwords visible if someone is capturing activity).